# Hex color range [java]

Tags: java, colors, hex

I am currently making a program for school and it involves colors. I get hex colors, but how do I define a range of hex colors to match just one.
For example, i want #ff1a1a,  #b30000, #e60000 and others to be considered as red (#ff0000). I don't really want to define them myself if i don't have to, so is there an easier way?

Comment: That example is hardly a range. Can you provide a more thorough example as well as some code, i.e. what you have so far?

Comment: You could check if the first byte is over a certain value and if the second and third bytes are under a certain other.
Ex: Red means the first byte is over A0, second and third under 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert to `HSV` and then use threshold for each color. For example, if you want to be conservative

1. Hue < 15 || Hue > 345
2. Saturation > 50%
3. 30% < Lightness < 60%

will give you `red`.

Here is an amazing [tool](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp) for you.